# ImageButton color getting changed to default on reloading the activity/app

Tags: android, button, imagebutton

On button (ImageButton) click I'm changing its background color to something else but as soon as I reload the app or open another activity and come back, the button's color gets changed to default. How can I change it permanently on click ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently when you change the color, it is in the scope of the activity. What you need to do is to save the color you want to set in `SharedPreferences` on click on of a button. And when in activity's `onCreate()` method, set the color which is saved in the `SharedPreferences` to the `ImageButton`.

> Save the color

```
private fun saveColor(color: Int) { // You will save the color ID here.
    val sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    sharedPrefs.edit()
        .putInt("ImageButtonColor", color)
        .apply()
}
```

> Get The saved color

```
private fun getColor(): Int {
    val sharedPrefs: SharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    return sharedPrefs.getInt("ImageButtonColor", -1)
}
```

> In your activity's `onCreate()`

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    if (getColor() != -1) { // If the color is not found, function will return -1. In that case, don't change the color. It will be case for fresh installed app.
        imageButton.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, getColor())) // Get color using color ID and set to the background.
    }

    button.setOnClickListener {
        saveColor(R.color.YOUR_COLOR)
    }

}
```

Comment: Actually, what I'm doing is.. I have a list of items of in my recyclerView and once I click on any button present in the list I want it to change any of the button's color. I'm able to do it but as you said it's in the scope of that adapter class only and once I reload/reopen the app, it gets changed to its default value. Could you please help with this precisely?

Comment: Please share some code that you have tried.

Comment: https://github.com/dilipSunar123/uDial/tree/main

Comment: please check the code in my github repo.. it the entire code of the Adapter Class of that recyclerview which i was mentioning you about...